How to to pin versions in Pipfile automatically
I want to stop pipenv to update all packages on every pipenv install somepackage
I'm aware of manually pinning versions in Pipfile, but how to do it automatically?
I read about lock and freeze, yet can't figure out that IMHO trivial task
